# Как создать два метода на один и тот же URL в REST-контроллере?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-mvc

У меня имеется эндпоинт `/reports`. Пользователь с ролью **STUDENT** делает запрос на данный эндпоинт и получает ответ. Изначально соответствующий метод в rest-контроллере выглядел вот так:

```
@GetMapping("/reports")
public ReportsTo getAll(@AuthenticationPrincipal AuthorizedUser user) {
    return service.getToByStudentId(user.getProfile().getId());
}
```

Я добавил роль **TUTOR** *(преподаватель)*. Пользователь с такой ролью тоже имеет доступ к методу `getAll()`. Как вы могли видеть, в предыдущем варианте я получал id студента из принципала, но теперь, когда я расширяю метод `getAll()`, такой способ уже не будет работать *(так как преподаватель содержит свой id, а не студента)*, и теперь метод выглядит вот так:

```
@GetMapping("/reports")
public ReportsTo getAll(@RequestParam(value = "student-id") Integer studentId,
                        @RequestParam(value = "theme-id", required = false) Integer themeId,
                        @AuthenticationPrincipal AuthorizedUser user) {
    return switch (user.getProfile().getRole()) {
        case STUDENT -> {
            checkIdCompliance(studentId, user.getProfile());
            yield service.getToByStudentIdAndThemeId(studentId, themeId);
        }
        case TUTOR -> {
            if (themeId == null) {
                throw new ResourceIsNotAllowedException("Theme id can not be null");
            }
            yield service.getToByStudentId(studentId, themeId, pagination);
        }
        default -> throw new ResourceIsNotAllowedException(
                "This resource is available only for users with the following roles: STUDENT, TUTOR");
        };
    }
```

Обратите внимание на параметры. Теперь мне приходится передавать в метод очень много лишних параметров. Например `themeId` не нужен студенту, как не нужен и `studentId`. В свою очередь для преподавателя лишним является получение принципала.

Я вижу здесь только одно решение: сделать два метода на один и тот же эндпоинт. Я представляю это вот так:

```
@GetMapping("/reports")
public ReportsTo getAll(@AuthenticationPrincipal AuthorizedUser user) {
    return service.getToByStudentId(user.getProfile().getId());
}

@GetMapping("/reports")
public ReportsTo getAll(@RequestParam(value = "student-id") Integer studentId,
                        @RequestParam(value = "theme-id") Integer themeId) {
    return service.getToByStudentIdAndThemeId(studentId, themeId);
}
```

Вот только это не будет работать, потому что Spring выдаст ошибку при наличии двух одинаковых эндпоинтов.

Проблема: разные роли могут иметь доступ к одному и тому же эндпоинту. При этом эндпоинт будет засоряться множеством параметров и проверок. Как эту проблему решить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Создать два одинаковых эндпоинта можно: укажите params

Суть в том, что при запуске `Spring Boot` приложения происходит регистрация всех эндопоинтов с использованием уникальной подписи. Подпись основана на следующих данных эндпоинта:

1. URI *(в моём случае `/reports`)*
2. HTTP-метод *(в моём случае `GET`)*
3. produces *(в моём случае `application/json`)*
4. consumes
5. params

Разумеется, если у двух эндпоинтов окажется одинаковая подпись, то возникнет ошибка. Уникальную подпись для двух эндопоинтов с одинаковым путём можно создать, если вынести параметры запроса в свойство `params`. Это выглядит вот так:

```
@GetMapping("/reports")
public ReportsTo getAll(@AuthenticationPrincipal AuthorizedUser user) {
    ...
}

@GetMapping(value = "/reports", params = { "student-id", "theme-id" })
public ReportsTo getAll(@RequestParam(value = "student-id") Integer studentId,
                        @RequestParam(value = "theme-id") Integer themeId) {
    ...
}
```

Теперь эти два эндпоинта будут считаться разными, и ошибки не возникнет.

Конечно, это не является идеальным решением. Если у вас есть два эндпоинта `/objects`, и вы укажете параметр `color` для первого и `size` для второго, то при таком запросе: `/objects?color=red&size=small` возникнет конфликт. Данный конфликт можно предупредить, если создать дефолтный эндпоинт с обоими параметрами, при этом лишний параметр можно игнорировать:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/objects", params = { "color", "size" })
public ReportsTo get(@RequestParam("color") String color) {
    ...
}
```

[Источник](http://tomaytotomato.com/overloading-rest-endpoints-on-spring-boot-2/)

### Ответ на вопрос

Мой вопрос звучал так:

> Проблема: разные роли могут иметь доступ к одному и тому же эндпоинту.
> При этом эндпоинт будет засоряться множеством параметров и проверок.
> Как эту проблему решить?

Несмотря на то, что я могу решить проблему, прибегнув к способу выше, я решил так не делать. [@Roman Konoval](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/218971/roman-konoval) подсказал более адекватное решение: эндпоинт для студента я назвал `/my-reports`, а эндпоинт для остальных ролей просто `/reports`.

Answer (score 1):

Проблема тут в том, что это два разных ендпоинта, которые вы пробуете слить в один. Они делают разные вещи, один для текущего пользователя, второй для кого-то другого.

Они получают разные обязательные параметры. И клиент всегда будет точно знать какой из вариантов он вызывает.

Comment: Да, я понимаю, что именно два одинаковых эндпоинта сделать нельзя. Просто я раздумывал над своим эндпоинтом именно с точки зрения REST ну и никак нельзя разделить. Судите сами: есть отчёты по пройденным темам. Студент получает отчёты по всем темам. Если отчёты хочет посмотреть преподаватель, то он смотрит их как правило по одной теме. Вот и получается такой эндпоинт: `reports?studentId=...&themeId=...`. И никак я его не могу разложить, да и не получится (если делать правильно).

Comment: Почему же нельзя разделить. `/myreports` и `/reports`. И еще раз самое главное - у них разные обязательные параметры и клиент всегда знает, какой из них он вызывает.

Comment: `/myreports` и `/reports` это забавно:) Впрочем хорошая идея, я почему-то не догадался. Действительно, можно сделать именно так. Так наверное и поступлю.

Comment: Есть алтернативный вариант, особенно если будет реализация проверки, что преподаватель имеет доступ (и тогда authorizeduser-а все равно придется передавать). Тогда имеет смысл в одном ендпоинте, но туда передавать studendId всегда. Тут зависит от того, какой смысл вкладывать в ендпоинт. Это один, но очень общий и позволяющий все - тогда, много параметров. Или это все же два отдельных.

Comment: Жаль конечно, что так. Ну да, иначе вариантов нет.

Comment: Мне подсказали, оказывается можно сделать одинаковые эндпоинты. http://tomaytotomato.com/overloading-rest-endpoints-on-spring-boot-2/

Answer (score 0):

Я бы даже на уровне контроллеров разделил.
`StudentController` с `@RequestMapping("student")`
и `TutorController` с `@RequestMapping("tutor")`
И тогда будет запрос идти на /tutor/reports, student/reports
А потом `@PreAuthorize` сразу на класс можно присобачить

А вообще вы же репорт не в контроллере генерируете а в сервисе каком-то верно ? У вас должно быть 2 разных метода в сервисе, и в контроллере вы решаете какой дергать на основе роли

Comment: Тогда будет выглядеть, как будто reports является подресурсом tutors. А это не так

Comment: согласен, перегнул. Тогда один ReportsController и по методу для каждой роли('reports/tutor','reports/student') или сделать интерфейс ReportResolver и реализации для разных ролей. И инжектить резолверы можно в Map<Role,ReportResolver> в самом контроллере, который имеет метод handle(paramsMap), тогда можно и один метод в контроллере иметь, который вызывает resolversMap.get(paramsMap.role).handle(paramsMap). Тогда для добавления функционала надо всего-лишь добавить новый resolver. Single Responsibility и маленькие классы будут

Comment: Ну так в reports/tutor то же самое - репетитор тем более не является подресурсом отчёта:)